# Cannot pass typed char array to open array of char?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, open-array-parameters

When compiled under Delphi 7 or Delphi XE, the code below complains

```
[DCC Error] Project1.dpr(25): E2010 Incompatible types: 'array of Char' and 'TAChar'
```

[According to Rudy's article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html), it should be allowed to pass typed array to open array ?

Furthermore, why does it not complain for 'array of Boolean' and 'TABoolean' ?

Many thanks for help !

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TAChar = array of Char;
  TABoolean = array of Boolean;

procedure Test1(const CharArr: array of Char);
begin
end;

procedure Test2(const BoolArr: array of Boolean);
begin
end;

var
  Arr1: TAChar;
  Arr2: TABoolean;
begin
  try
    Test1(Arr1);  //  <------- Does not compile in Delphi 7 & XE
    Test2(Arr2);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: This seems pretty hard to believe! Would be a compiler bug if it is so.

Comment: The code compiles successfully in Delphi XE5

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh!... O_O

Comment: Compiles in XE2 but not Delphi 2007. This link might be interesting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780235/delphi-array-of-char-and-tchararray-incompatible-types

Comment: It also compiles correctly in D2007.

Comment: perhaps it is a compiler bug stemming from a special-case handling of PChar

Comment: Unfortunately the top voted answer at that other question is terrible

Comment: Thank you very much for your information !

Answer (score 6):

The code in the question is valid. Any compiler that refuses to compile it is defective. Probably there is little point submitting a bug report because modern versions will compile this code.

If you cannot move to a compiler that is not defective then you will have to work around the defect. Sertac's answer to a similar question demonstrates one such work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781425/505088